# UITableview showing only certain rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

All,

I have one table view it only shows the top 3 results. I have done this in XCODE by doing row size and tableview height.

I to be able to press a button (which is fine) and opened another view controller which is fine also and show another tableview without the top 3 results. So it only wants to show the reminder of the table rows. So if there is 20 in the array it needs to show 4 - 20. Anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: Can't understand you SO SO. Please be clear and edit the question to better undestand

Comment: Can you please provide some code examples, state what it is you're looking for exactly, and how it differs from what you have currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new array based on the existing one:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // TRIM THE ORIGINAL ARRAY HERE
    tableDataArray = [self arrayWithContentsOfArray:originalArray afterIndex:3];

}

-(NSMutableArray*)arrayWithContentsOfArray:(NSArray*)originalArray afterIndex:(int)index{

    NSMutableArray *desiredResultsArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for ( int i = index; i < [originalArray count]; i++ ) {
        [desiredResultsArray addObject:[originalArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    return desiredResultsArray;

}
```

Comment: Then pass that array over the segue, and then obviously add the tableview delegate etc ?

Comment: You can either pass this before segue or pass the original array and perform the trim in viewDidLoad of new view controller.

Comment: fair enough, i will pass the original array and mess around with it in the new view controller. Thanks wingNut.